# how to Passing JSON to Twig?

Tags: php, twig

I am a beginner developer currently studying twig.
I'm trying to parse JSON in twig, but currently no progress.
I'm trying to put the link in a variable called tld but I don't have a solution for this.

```
    {% set tld = assets.php.testLocalData.get('live_link') %}
    <a href="{{tld}}">
```

This code is my JSON file(ver.php).

testLocalData.php

```
    <?php
    return[
    'test_link' => 
    [
        'live_link' => 'link_move'
    ]
    ];
```

The json file and twig file have different directories.
Any solution for this?

edit : testLocalData file path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g68Ye.png)

Comment: What framework are your using here? I've not seen the construct `assets.php` yet so far? Also there isn't any JSON in `testLocalData.php`

Comment: framework is ec-cube. and i referred to this site (https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19704/passing-json-to-twig). 'testLocalData.php' is assets/php in file.

Comment: So I'm guessing the construct you are using, `assets.php.testLocalData`, does not exist? You are getting errors right if you try to run it that way? You got an documentation in english for this framework?

Comment: sorry i dont have documentation in english. i added picture file path.

Comment: okay, i'll give this a shot a bit later on then

Comment: really thank you.